# What does this %s value mean?

Tags: php, html

I'm just reading some code and I came across:

```
form method='post'
input type='hidden' name='input' value='%s'
```

What does the **%s** mean?  I tried googling but I can't get an answer for this one.

Comment: To me - it means nothing, to the one who wrote it - it probably means a lot :)

Comment: Too little context. Most common use would be a placeholder in a printf-type format string. But could be anything without more information.

Comment: It's just some hardcoded value that the author wants to send to the app when the form is submitted.  Without the app code there's no way of knowing.  It's not markup.

Comment: This Appears to be a Format String of a `printf`-style Function, possibly an Artefact of a flawed `printf` call with only 1 argument.

Comment: It has no specific meaning to `HTML` or `PHP` if that is what you are asking. It is just like coding `<input type='hidden' name='input' value='Fred'>`. It means something to the application but its just data.

Answer (score 1):

%s most likely means a string. Sort of like a placeholder or variable.

In some languages you can write something like:

```
string name = "Joe";
printf("Hi %s", name);
```

Which would print out: "Hi Joe".

Answer (score 1):

`%s` is used in a programming technique called 'variable interpolation'.

it will be replaced by a string somewhere later in the program

Comment: How is “interpolation” any more correct than “placeholder”? (I’d call it “formatting specifier”, personally.)